# I am going to go?

Tags: grammaticality, progressive-aspect

My English teacher told me that "going to go" doesn't exist in English but I saw it many times. For example "The whole band is going to go to show their support". I'd like to know if it's possible to use it or not.

Comment: Your teacher is incompetent, as attested by 33 million written instances of [going to go](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22going+to+go%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3517/8019

Comment: I'd prefer "All the band are going to go, to show their support" to divide the different but confusingly similar-looking structures here. _Be going_ catenates, taking a to-infinitive (some might even consider it an auxiliary). The second _to_ is the preposition, here with the sense 'in order to' or 'with the intention of [-ing form]' - French _pour_.

Comment: I had the same problem with the English teacher. I said "going to go" and she said that it doesn't exist. I guess it actually does but she's wrong.

Comment: In any case, your teacher might simply want you to avoid saying things like: *I'm going to go to read my grammar books this evening.*

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's fine, providing you want it to mean what it says.

*Going to...* indicates a future action:

> I'm going to hit him
>   I'm going to vomit

So you can express the future action of going somewhere:

> I'm going to go somewhere

You can add the reason for that future action.

> I'm going to hit him to show my disapproval.
>   I'm going to go to show support.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use "going to" before a verb when you already knew in advance that you'd be doing that. For instance, "I'm going to tell this to my English teacher".

And Go is not an exception. You can perfectly well say "I'm going to go home tomorrow".